How can I create multipages? With Vue3
Hi I am working on a project made with vue cli .
I want to create a multipage.
My folder structure
-public
-index.html
-src
---App.vue
---pages
-----about
-------index.html
-------About.vue
<!-- ./src/pages/about/index.html -->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <link
          rel="icon"
          href="/favicon.ico"
        >
        <meta
          name="viewport"
          content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"
        >
        <title>About</title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div id="app"></div>
        <script type="module">
            import { createApp } from "vue";
            import About from "./About.vue";

            createApp(About).mount("#app");
        </script>
    </body>

</html>

<!-- ./index.html -->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <link
          rel="icon"
          href="/favicon.ico"
        >
        <meta
          name="viewport"
          content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"
        >
        <title>Home</title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div id="app"></div>
        <script type="module">
            import { createApp } from "vue";
            import App from "./App.vue";

            createApp(App).mount("#app");
        </script>
    </body>

</html>

This is my vite.config.js
import { fileURLToPath, URL } from 'node:url'

import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import vue from '@vitejs/plugin-vue'
import { resolve } from "path";

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
    plugins: [
        vue(),
    ],
    resolve: {
        alias: {
            '@': fileURLToPath(new URL('./src', import.meta.url))
        }
    },
    build: {
        rollupOptions: {
            input: {
                main: resolve(__dirname, 'index.html'),
                inquiry: resolve(__dirname, 'src/pages/inquiry/index.html')
            }
        }
    }
})


What I referenced https://vitejs.dev/guide/build.html#multi-page-app
But my page is still in main.
What's wrong with my code?
I can't use SPA.
Help me, you're geniuses, right?

https://router.vuejs.org/

@imhvost I don't need SPA.

Interesting. So what do you need?

@imhvost I need multi page application like ssr. but not ssr

vue does not work this way. choose different technology

@BorisMaslennikov It can't be... vite can do it. maybe.... vue cli‘s config has "pages" option. Vue can implement MPA that setup. I can't use any other technology. This is a customer requirement
